# Small wind generator project

Tags: led, motor, dc, generator, drill

Why when I spin a dc motor (USED AS A GENERATOR )with drill it does not light up led , but when I spin it with my fingers it light up

Comment: You might spin it into the wrong direction.

Comment: When you spin it with the drill, are you still holding the body (stator) still?

Comment: I can start up my fan by moving my CNC stepper motor when in idle current off motor V depends on Speed they the magnetic peak field and polarity. You would need a full wave bridge to make it bidirectional.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you are spinning the wrong direction with the drill. Try switching the drill into reverse direction or reverse the LED connections.

[image]

*Figure 1. A water check or non-return valve only allows current to flow in one direction. Diodes are similar in that they only allow current to flow in one direction as indicated by the arrow in the symbol. Source: [What is an LED?](http://lednique.com/what-is-an-led/).*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsmZA6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. The circuit symbol for an LED.*

LEDs are light emitting *diodes* and only conduct current in the direction of the arrow.